# Will I be lost in AC 3 if I skip AC Brotherhood and Revelations?

Tags: assassins-creed-series

I have played Assassin's Creed 1 and 2. I would like to skip over Brotherhood and Revelations if possible just to save time and go straight to AC 3. Would skipping those two games leave me lost in AC 3?

Answer (score 4):

As far as the past Assassins' story goes, you won't be lost. Ezio's story is largely unrelated to Connor's except for the main fact that they're both connected through Desmond.

As far as the present-day Assassins' story goes, everything concerning Desmond and his party ***WILL*** fly over your head if you miss *Brotherhood* and *Revelations*, especially everything related to Juno, Minerva and Tinia.

So if you want to fully understand the WHOLE story, I highly suggest you don't skip the Ezio trilogy. They're not even that expensive on Steam. =p

Answer (score 1):

No you wouldn't be lost. I skipped over one of the expansions (revelations I think) and didn't finish the other, I followed AC3 just fine.

However, there were parts of AC3 (when you play as Desmond instead of Connor) that I found incredibly boring and unenjoyable; perhaps that's related to the fact that I was missing some storyline context from the previous games.

Comment: I would say that some elements of the Desmond sequences are going to fly over your head if you haven't played Brotherhood and Revelations (notably "Where the hell is Lucy?"...I *had* played them and even found myself confused at one point when they were discussing it.)

Comment: Just to clarfiy for myself and anyone else who sees this but are all AC games seperate from one another? The way I remember it only AC2 and Brotherhood are related which is why it was named Brotherhood and not 3

Comment: No the are not separate; all of the AC games are intertwined by Desmond's story and the plot of Templars vs Assassins. The individual plot of each game's main hero is separate of course, because they occur in vastly different time periods and encounter different challenges (for example, Connor's story during the American Revolution), but they are all connected at a higher level.

If that's news to you, I'd suggest you go back to AC1 and play through all/most of the games.